# About "活きてるなあって思いますか？"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In this video clip : https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxfiBqUAzxHmyxBNLZ13fJBoIpmqOrFBQq

The lady asks :

> 剣道で培ったことは日頃の自分にもすごい活きてるなあって思いますか？

The subtitle trasnlation says ：

> Do you feel that you're applying what you acquired through Kendo into
> daily life?

I can't exactly break down `活きてるなあって`. In the dictionary I found 活きてる（＝活きている） is "be live" or "be of effect" or "be applied (in this context)". So I can understand it is translated `"Do you think the things you learned from Kendo is alive also to your every day's life?"` (it's not easy to translate one-to-one in English because the word order is different and can't find exactly matching word in English in many cases).
My question is : Why is it `~なあって思いますか?`?  Shouldn't it be `~なのがあると思いますか？`?　Or is it another way of saying the same thing？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This な(あ) is [this sentence-ending particle](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/advanced-sentence-ending-particles/#2), so 活きてるなあ means something along the lines of "(oh) it's alive/functioning!". This って is an informal quotative particle (=と). Thus a literal translation would be:

> 「剣道で培ったことは日頃の自分にもすごい活きてるなあ」って思いますか？
> =「剣道で培ったことは日頃の自分にもすごい活きてるなあ」と思いますか？
>
> Do you think "(oh) what I cultivated through kendo is really alive also in my everyday self"?

なの doesn't follow a verb, so 活きてるなのがある is plain ungrammatical and makes no sense.

Comment: Ah I didn't know the なあ form and the って. Not knowing what those are, I couldn't look it up in the dictionary. Thank you!